# Find previous equivalent dates over the past two calender years

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If today is say 15th August 2012 then the query should return the following

```
15/01/2011,
15/02/2011,
...
...
15/07/2012
15/08/2012
```

If today is 31st August 2012 then the query would return

```
31/01/2011,
28/02/2011,  <<<<this is the nearest date
...
...
31/07/2012
31/08/2012
```

We have a vw_DimDate in our Warehouse which should help

**edit**
It contains the following fields

[image]

Currently I'm using the following but it seems rather convoluted! ...

```
DECLARE @Dt DATETIME = '31 JUL 2012'--GETDATE()

;WITH DateSet_cte(DayMarker)
        AS
        (
        SELECT DayMarker
        FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate
        WHERE 
                DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(4),DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@Dt),112) + '0101') AND
                DayMarker <=@Dt
        )
, MaxDate_cte(MaxDate)
        AS
        (
        SELECT [MaxDate] = MAX(DayMarker)
        FROM DateSet_cte 
        )       
SELECT
            [Mth] = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),a.DayMarker,112) + '01')
            , MAX(a.DayMarker) [EquivDate]
FROM DateSet_cte a
WHERE DAY(a.DayMarker) <= (SELECT DAY([MaxDate]) FROM MaxDate_cte)
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),a.DayMarker,112) + '01')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with Numbers as (
    select distinct number from master..spt_values where number between 0 and 23
), Today as (
    select CONVERT(date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as d
)
select
    DATEADD(month,-number,d)
from
    Numbers,Today
where DATEPART(year,DATEADD(month,-number,d)) >= DATEPART(year,d) - 1
```

Seems odd to want a variable number of returned values based on how far through the year we are, but that's what I've implemented.

When you use `DATEADD` to add `month`s to a value, then it automatically adjusts the day number if it would have produced an out of range date (e.g. 31st February), such that it's the last day of the month. Or, as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) puts it:

> If *datepart* is **month** and the *date* month has more days than the return month and the *date* day does not exist in the return month, the last day of the return month is returned.

Of course, if you already have a numbers table in your database, you can eliminate the first CTE. You mentioned that you "have a vw_DimDate in our Warehouse which should help", but since I have *no* idea on what that (presumably, a) view contains, it wasn't any help.

Comment: +1. ..not so odd if you have running totals in a different field but you wish to isolate just the MTD figures that occured at equivalent month to dates - and then use those in a graph

Comment: is it safe to use master..spt_values? ... are any positive numbers missing (I ask as I've never used it before and I see the first two numbers in it are -32,768 and then jumps to -1)

Comment: @whytheq - lots of people do, if you just need a low range of positive numbers, it's got a lot of them (certainly up into the 100s). If it makes you nervous, then you can either populate a `Numbers` table for your own use, or cross-join `sys.objects` to itself several times, then apply `ROW_NUMBER()` over the result set to guarantee production of the numbers you need.

Comment: @whytheq - I don't think the view will help any - with `DATEADD` handily already having the kind of rounding behaviour we want, a `DATEADD` based solution seems like it will be the most straightforward.

Comment: I like the `WHERE` clause - not too sure if it's an acceptible adjective but that `WHERE` clause is very _pretty_

Comment: one more question; I assume these two bits of code are the same `TableA, TableB` == `TableA CROSS JOIN TableB`?

Comment: @whytheq - yes, it's a cross join. If there were any other tables in the query, I'd probably have made it explicit, but I tend to just use `,` when I just want to cross join two tables to obtain my result.